# How to handle invalid JSON coming from the server(the source) in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

In my application, I have to make a web service call which returns an array of objects as JSON through which I need to iterate and construct my UI dynamically (for each object in the array).

The problem is, for certain requests, I get invalid/bad JSON and hence, the jquery.parse() simply fails and code crashes. I can't know beforehand though, for which request I would get an invalid JSON!

Is there any way to avoid application from crashing due to the bad JSON? I know one way is to change the JSON at the source itself or use a try-catch in the JS. But, is there any way I can handle the bad JSON scenarios and construct a valid one from it may be. like any available libraries or any algorithm to convert possible bad JSON into a valid one?

One such bad JSON would be:

`"key1":"http://someUrl.com/somePath/path2/catalog.do?someVal\u003dsearch\u0026q\u003d""foo+bar"","key2":""...`

In the above scenario, the 2 consecutive double quotes before and after foo+ bar is causing the issue here.It should be somewhat like this instead:

`"key1":"http://someUrl.com/somePath/path2/catalog.do?someVal\u003dsearch\u0026q\u003d","foo+bar:"","key2":""...`

(Added a coma , before foo+bar and a colon : after foo+bar).But there may be other causes for bad JSON also I guess.

I am using JS and JQuery(v 1.10.x) in the UI.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of the invalid JSON?

Comment: I would usually check for validity first - if invalid, return something - else, continue with the code as usual.
Otherwise you could check for validity - if invalid, set to a valid value, continue...

Comment: Do you have control on the service's server-side code and in which language is it written? For example, i already noticed small validity issues when exporting server-side PHP with `json_encode` and its decoding in javascript (for unicode characters IIRC)

Comment: Don't try to 'fix' broken data client side, that's a prime recipe for headaches and bugs, since it blurs the line between what is and isn't correct data. The service should be the single point of truth and return either correct data, or an error. ( 400 bad request, if the response isn't valid )

Comment: @Shilly I don't disagree, but that only works if you have control over the server which may not be the case here.

Comment: "key1":"http://someVal.com/Path1/Path2?route\u003dsearch\u0026q\u003d""foo+bar"" , "key2":"..."...  if you take a look here, before the foo+bar, there are 2 double quotes which caused the issue in one scenario (this is a dummy data representation of the actual one but with same format).  @EvanKnowles

Comment: @surya please edit it into the question rather posting as a comment. Also, those extra double quotes are going to be hard to deal with.

Comment: this is one error case, with 2 double quotes being the cause..but there can be other causes as well..@EvanKnowles

Comment: @JaredSmith sure.Right away :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Very true. If the OP does not have service control, personally I would still prefer try/catch and handling the error over 'fixing the data', unless 'fixing' it only means like adding/removing correct quotes etc.

Comment: @Kaddath unfortunately the web services are handled by completely different teams who hhhave tons of JSON data for various inputs and asking them to check for the validity of individualy JSON response would not be feasible I guess.

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidthow can we set to valid value incase it is invalid..could you please elaborate a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @surya If someone thinks they're generating JSON, they have absolutely no idea what they're doing and have no business creating APIs for you and others to use.  Someone is trying to roll their own JSON serializer, which is asinine and should be avoided at all costs.  Go find this other team, other company, whatever it is, and tell them they're wrong and they need to fix it.  This isn't something you can fix and expect to have working at all.  And, don't forget, you're likely to end up with the blame for this problem.  If it can't be fixed, I'd seriously consider getting a new job.

Comment: @surya Also, jQuery 1.10.0 is ancient.  If there's a particular reason you need the 1.x.x branch, at least upgrade to 1.12.4, which was the last build of it.

Comment: Brad is right, there is absolutely no reason for any server to produce invalid JSON - almost every language has libraries which can automatically produce valid JSON from a code object in that language. Building it manually or using some home-made methodology - resulting in these kind of silly problems - is a crazy thing to do. You need to refuse to work with this data until the API is fixed. Trying to work round the various problems (including some you might not have seen yet!) is going to be complicated, hard work and most importantly a waste of your valuable time and effort (and maybe money)

Comment: @brad Agree :) and also mine is kind of a pretty old code-base running in production and hence the JQuery version :)

Comment: @surya All the more reason to fix things correctly...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to win any prizes for beauty, but it should get the job done:

```
const reg = /"\w+"\s*:\s*"([\w\s\.\$\/\\\?\+"\=\&]*)",/;
const result = `"key1":"someVal.com/Path1/Path2?route\u003dsearch\u0026q\u003d""foo+bar"", "key2":"..."`;
let match;
while (match = reg.exec(result)) {
  result = result.replace(match[1], match[1].replace(/"/g, `'`));
}
console.log(JSON.parse('{' + result + '}');
```